Extracting role from string in variable
I have a variable which could either be var=Role or var=AdminRole.
I want to be able to do the following:
if $var = "Role"
then
set role variable as $var
else
if $var = "AdminRole"
then
set role variable as just the prefix without Role keyword

This is not working:
if [[ $var == *"AdminRole"* ]];
then
Role=`echo $var | sed s/Role//`
elif [[ $var == "Role" ]];
then
Role=$var
fi

Looking for help on how to do this.

Learn to check your code at https://shellcheck.net . When you've corrected all errors flagged and you still have trouble, then post a question here and indicated you have used shellcheck.

What does “This is not working” mean?  What debugging did you do, and what were the results?  Are your if statements working correctly?  (Add statements like echo "In first branch; doing sed..." to track the flow of control.)  Are you having problems with the assignment, per se, or the command substitution?  (Try doing echo "$var" | sed s/Role// without redirecting or capturing the output.)      Also, if the variable could be "AdminRole", "AccountRole" or "AssistRole", as you say in a comment, you need to say that in the question.

It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking for, but probably something like this:
#!/bin/bash

var="AdminRole"  # Or "Role"

if [[ $var == Role ]]; then
    echo Action1
elif [[ $var == *Role ]]; then
    # Remove "Role" from the end
    echo "${var%Role}"
else
    echo "Unrecognized role"
fi


I do not know what the variable var would be. It could be a variation of "AdminRole", "AccountRole", "AssistRole" or just "Role". I just want to be able to perform a different action if its just "Role" without the prefix. So for example if $var was with a prefix then I want that to be a different action. Basically its a substring match versus an exact string match and how do I do that.

@gdba Then just match *Role. Updated the answer.

Thank you Chris. This helped.

If one of the answers here solved your issue, @gdba, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

You could use a case statement:
case $var in 
  (Role) Role=$var
  ;; 
  (*Role) Role=${var%Role}
  ;;
  (*) # do some error handling
  ;;
esac

Alternatively you could remove the Role suffix unconditionally, then assign the value Role if the result is empty:
Role=${var%Role}
: "${Role:=$var}"

(you could replace $var by literal Role in the last expression if you find it clearer).
